# the extension php-intl isn't loading

Tags: codeigniter-4, php-extension

I'm trying to install and use codeigniter4.
After using the `php spark serve` cmd, I got the error :

> The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: intl.
> at SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php:226

However I have in my php.ini file extension=intl and the php-intl.dll file in the /ext folder.

I assume that I just need to load it or something like that, but I can't find how. All the other extensions in the php.ini and /ext folder where loaded by default.

`php info` show me all the extension except this one that I need.

Sorry if it's already been asked/answered.

Edit: im using xampp and im using windows

Edit2: I solved it by removing the completely the extension line from the file -> saved, then paste it back -> saved. And it worked.

Comment: Which version of PHP? Can you also have a look at your php log files? Are you sure you have removed the semi column in front of the intl ext line?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu/Linux and nginx write the following command in your terminal
I am facing the same error and this will works for me. But i have Ubuntu/Linux based system.

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```